# What effect has a statement like 'var and do_something_with(var)' in Python?

Tags: python

While looking for some answers in a package source code (*colander* to be specific) I stumbled upon a string that I cannot comprehend. Also my *PyCharm* frowns on it with 'statement seems to have no effect'.

Here's the code abstract:

```
...
for path in e.paths():
    keyparts = []
    msgs = []
    for exc in path:
        exc.msg and msgs.extend(exc.messages()) # <-- what is that?
        keyname = exc._keyname()
        keyname and keyparts.append(keyname) # <-- and that
    errors['.'.join(keyparts)] = '; '.join(interpolate(msgs))
return errors
...
```

It seems to be extremely pythonic and I want to master it!

UPD. So, as I see it's not pythonic at all - readability is harmed for the sake of shorthand.

Comment: +1 - this is a good question, that's really weird and I have no idea why one would do it. I would argue it isn't Pythonic at all however - readability is one of the most important things in Python, and if you look at it and ask 'why do that', it's not Pythonic.

Comment: @Lattyware I agree about a serious readabilty issue with that, was mostly joking about pytonic:)

Comment: @Lattyware: If you're asking because you don't know how `and` and `or` work it's not a reflection on its Pythonicness.  Using `and` as a guard is very Pythonic.

Comment: @EthanFurman I understand how `and` and `or` work in Python, but I've never been a fan of using stuff like that in this kind of way. It has the potential for bugs and is harder to read. Using an `if` statement is always a better solution.

Comment: @Lattyware: I know you do, I don't think yentsun did; I find it very easy to read (although complex statements should be broken out); careful of using `always`, as `always` rarely is.  ;)

Comment: @Ethan Furman I also understand how `and` and `or` work in python and thats why I asked the question. For me, the statement looked like `truth and truth` or `truth and false` and without any hints it looked senseless (_without a hint_ is key here). I also can guess that it will look senseless for many other people. Will I use this in my own code - probably not. I turned away from PHP to Python for readability and I can give you tons of such vague (but short) constructions in PHP.

Comment: If you understood `and` and `or`, *and* their short-circuiting behavior, why then did you say `I stumbled upon a string that I cannot comprehend`?

Comment: @Ethan Furman I didn't know anything about _short-circuiting behavior_ though I claim the right to say _I also understand how `and` and `or` work in python_. I believe I don't have to know about all of the exploits (yep I'd call use of _short-circuiting_ an exploit) to understand and write good python code.

Comment: No disrepect intended, but I can't agree: the short-circuiting behavior is as integral to Python's `and`/`or` as is `and`/`or` returning the last/first item that decides the truthiness (or 'somethingness') of the expression:  `a = 1 and 2; assert a == 2; b = ['this'] and None; assert b is None; c = 'that' or ''; assert c == 'that'; d = None or 0; assert d == 0`.

Comment: @Ethan Furman I see. To be honest, I like and use some of the above examples (`a = b or c` - love it!). But most of them are clear and do not rise any questions even if you don't know about 'short-circuiting'. But is there any benefit in using `a and do_something()` instead of `if a: do_something()`?

Comment: Nope -- it's mostly a matter of style and comfort level with implied `if`s; I'm going to back-up a little: I just read the example code again, and it's more along the lines of using a list comprehension such as `[foo(x) for x in some_list]` without assigning the list to anything -- it gets thrown away, and was only used for the side-effect of running `foo()` over `some_list`;  without the assignment or `if` check, `a and do_something()` is going only for the side-effect, which is not very Pythonic.  To be clear, it's the throwing away of `do_something()`s return value that is unPythonic.

Comment: [being warned about extending discussions] Thank you, Ethan - I leraned new things with your help today, and to sum up the discussion - _short-circuit evaluation_ is modern and widely used technique (and it is pythonic). But that paticular one-liner `a and do_something()` is not quite pythonic and is a matter of code style. Am I correct?

Comment: @Lattyware: looking at the code snippet again, I find I agree with you (although maybe not for the same reasons ;) -- using the short-circuiting behavior solely for the side effect of (not) executing a function is not very Pythonic; however, if the result of `do_something()` was used (assigned to a name, used in an `if`, etc) then I would have no problem with it.

Comment: Correct.  I could see myself using this technique if I had several such lines that would execute one after the other: `arg1 and do_something(); arg2 and do_something_else(); arg1 or arg2 and optional()`.  In a case like this it could read better than multiple tiny `if` blocks (I don't care for `if` one-liners).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If keyname evaluates to False, the `and` statement will return false immediately and not evaluate the second part.  Otherwise, it will evaluate the second part (not that the return value matters in this case).  So it's basically equivalent to:

```
if keyname: 
    keyparts.append(keyname)
```

I'm not sure that it's very pythonic though, since the the version I just suggested seem much more readable (to me personally, at least).

Comment: Agreed. OP's example violates "explicit is better than implicit" for no good reason.

Comment: Second example is invalid syntax on python2 and python3.  don't do that.

Comment: Thanks - its clear now. I was close to that idea but just couldnt absolutely define what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

`and` and `or` are [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) logical operators; which means as soon as Python knows what the answer must be, it stops evaluating any remaining clauses.

In the snippet you posted `and` is being used to guard the `.extend()` and `.append()` functions -- presumably the author does not want to post, for example, `None` into the lists.

I typically use this feature in `if` statements:

```
if name and name[0] in ('Mr', 'Mrs', 'Ms'):
    ...
```

`name` is a possibly empty list -- if it is empty, `name[0]` will fail with an `IndexError`, so I guard it with `name and` -- if `name` *is* empty, `name[0]` (and the `if` block) do not execute and the error is avoided.

This is a *very* Pythonic feature.

Comment: If name has one element in your example, you're in trouble.  name[0] would make the example more obviously correct.

Comment: @happydave, Good point, thanks.  In the original snippet `name` would always have at least two elements if it existed at all, but that was not apparent when taken out of context.

Comment: @EthanFurman +1 for the link and explaining the reason behind that structure. Also I like that its called 'to guard' - now I know how to address it at least. In your example though, I see more sense in using  the guard, because you have 'if'. But the original example `a and b.method()` has bad readability and a pure trap for newcomers (I can imagine how mature pythonists love it:)

Answer (score 2):

Since in python the first expression in an `and` statement is evaluated before the second and the interpreter breaks out of evaluating the `and` statement if the first expression is `False`,

```
keyname and keyparts.append(keyname)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if keyname:
    keyparts.append(keyname)
```